# Open a Form Dialog after x seconds

Tags: c#

I'm looking to impliment a method that executes a potentially lengthy or short task. I have a 'Loading' Dialog and this needs to be shown after about 3 seconds while allowing the main execution to go ahead. So far I've thought about using a timer:

```
        var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var elapsedMs = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if(elapsedMs == 3000)
        {
           loader.Show();
        }
```

But the obvious problem is that the if statement is already passed. Does anyone have a suggestion as to how this could be approached?

Comment: Wouldnt a splash-screen be a better solution?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?

Comment: No splash screen possible in this case unfortunately, this is Windows Forms.

Comment: You can wrap task execution to automate displaying "Loading" dialog. The timer is the obvious choice. The idea is to start timer before you start the task and if timer event occurs - show form. When task is finished it has to stop timer (if stopped before interval is expired - you will not see the form) and close that form.